# Advantages and disadvantages of Spring caching, Hazelcast and Redis?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-jpa, hazelcast

Well I'm quite new in this caching thing, so wondering what are the benefits this caching mechanisms provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can combine the Spring caching with either Hazelcast or Redis as an underlying cache provider.

By default, Spring uses `ConcurrentHashMap` for caching which provides only basic functionality and is not distributed. On the other hand, Hazelcast and Redis are distributed caching solutions.

Here are some good resources on this topic:

- [Caching with Spring Boot and Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/blog/spring-boot/)
- [DB Engines: Comparison Hazelcast vs. Memcached vs. Redis](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Hazelcast%3BMemcached%3BRedis)
- [DZone: Hazelcast vs ElastiCache (Memcached)](https://dzone.com/articles/hazelcast-vs-elasticache-memcached)
- [Compare Hazelcast and Redis](https://hazelcast.org/compare-with-redis/)